# Decimal Alignment in tabulary package

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

How to achieve Decimal alignment as well auto fit table in tabulary package, below is my code, or is there any other way to achieve both, please guide,

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{0.9\textwidth}{LLCL}
\hline
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.1 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\hline
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.441 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
Definition and Validation of Dynamic &1.2 & Definition and Validation of  & Definition and Validation of \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{center}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement that *all* columns should be `LCR`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.9\textwidth}{LS[table-format=1.3]CL}
\hline
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.1 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\hline
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.441 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
Definition and Validation of Dynamic &1.2 & Definition and Validation of  & Definition and Validation of \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the setting to `\arraystretch`. If you want a better layout, use `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx,booktabs}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.9\textwidth}{LS[table-format=1.3]CL}
\toprule
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.1 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\midrule
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.441 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\addlinespace
Definition and Validation of Dynamic &1.2 & Definition and Validation of  & Definition and Validation of \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `dcolumn`, instead of `siunitx` (but I recommend updating your TeX distribution anyway).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,dcolumn,booktabs}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.9\textwidth}{LD{.}{.}{1.3}CL}
\toprule
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.1 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\midrule
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.441 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\addlinespace
Definition and Validation of Dynamic &1.2 & Definition and Validation of  & Definition and Validation of \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am getting some expl13.sty error, we are using Miktex 2.7 version, will it work there??

Comment: @user52124 Surely not: MiKTeX is currently at version 2.9. I added a version using `dcolumn`. But update your TeX system nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate for your help, very soon i have to upgrade my Tex system :-)

Comment: Is it possible to have Auto Continuation of Table like we have in longtable combined with tabulary, dcolumn packages??

Answer (score 2):

Just use an aligned column, as normal:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table 1 }\label{table_specrot}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.9\textwidth}{LD..{1.2}CL}
\hline
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.1 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
\hline
Definition and Validation of Dynamic Video Reframing based on &1.441 & Definition and Validation of & Definition and Validation of Dynamic \\
Definition and Validation of Dynamic &1.2 & Definition and Validation of  & Definition and Validation of \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{table}
```